# Rails 3 continues to use ruby 1.8.7 even though "ruby -v" states 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have finished developing my app and am currently deploying it. I'm getting a weird error from one of my controllers:

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'

When I run it in my dev environment it works fine. The only difference I can see between dev/prod is that dev is is using Ruby 1.9.2 and Prod is using 1.8.7. In my naivete I thought "Oh I'll just upgrade to 1.9.2" - what I fool I've been. I used RVM, changed my path, started new terminal session and now can see ruby is at 1.9.2:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
```

However, when I run a "rails s" my computer continues to use 1.8.7:

```
[2011-10-05 05:58:40] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1 
[2011-10-05 05:58:40] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16) [x86_64-linux] 
[2011-10-05 05:58:45] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=32574 port=3000
```

What the what!!!? I hope someone can help me. I'm about 15 minutes away from moving to the country, and become a farmer!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you set default ruby with `rvm --default use 1.9.2` command?

Comment: @Bohdan: Yep,  
rvm list default
Default Ruby (for new shells)
   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]

Comment: what is the output of `sudo ruby -v` ?

Comment: WOW! 'sudo ruby -v' gives me 1.8.7. Yet when I do 'sudo su', 'ruby -v' I get 1.9.2. Any idea how I'd go about fixing that? Thanks.

Comment: I try to ;)
That's been giving me some problems after upgrading to 1.9.2, though. Why? You think that might have something todo with my errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you used sudo when installed it might be the reason

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

uses system ruby. Try

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

which should produce proper config files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `rvm reload` ? sometimes when I get strange errors like that reloading rvm fixes it.

Comment: Yeah, just tried that. No luck unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion, though.